# Load expandable components minimized

Tags: react-native

I am trying to to load my component on its minimized, but nothing i've tried so far seems to work.
Below is my component:
It is a collapsable component with dropdown arrows and there a bunch of them in the parent component, but they all load expanded.
It would be much cleaner to load them all minimized and then the user could choose to expand them.

```
import { StyleSheet,Text,View,Image,TouchableHighlight,Animated } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export class ExpanderView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.icons = {
      'up': require('./images/Arrowhead-01-128.png'),
      'down'  : require('./images/Arrowhead-Down-01-128.png')
    };
    this.state = {
      animation: new Animated.Value(),
      expanded: true
    };

  }

  toggle() {
    let initialValue    = this.state.expanded? this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight : this.state.minHeight,
        finalValue      = this.state.expanded? this.state.minHeight : this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight;

    this.setState({
      expanded: !this.state.expanded
    });

    this.state.animation.setValue(initialValue);
    Animated.spring(
      this.state.animation, 
      {toValue: finalValue}
    ).start();
  }

  _setMaxHeight(event) {
    this.setState({
      maxHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
  }

  _setMinHeight(event) {
    this.setState({
      minHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
  }

  render() {
    let icon = this.icons['down'];

    if (this.state.expanded) {
      icon = this.icons['up'];
    }
    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.container, {height: this.state.animation}]}>
         <View style={styles.titleContainer} onLayout={this._setMinHeight.bind(this)}>
          {/* // Passing props as state variable ain't right */}
            <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}
              underlayColor="#f1f1f1">

              <Image style={styles.buttonImage} source={icon}></Image>

            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.body} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    margin: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  inputWrap: {
    flex: 1
  },
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#2a2f43',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  button: {

  },
  buttonImage: {
    width: 30,
    height: 25
  },
  body: {
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 0
  }
});
```

I'm guessing it's achievable manipulating the styles.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for now:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.toggle();
    }, 45); 
  }
```

It works well, but it is not the desired behavior.